# Как поменять версию php для apche2?

Tags: php, apache, macos, apache2.4

Всегда работал с `linux` и проблем с этим не было, но сейчас начал работать на `Mac OS X EL Capitan` и проблема в следующем: 
Стоит `php55` и `php56` ставилось через `homebrew` и проблема в том, что делаю в консоли `php -v` выдает `PHP 5.6.29`, а `phpinfo()` показывает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть консольная версия и версия для `apache` разные!

*Прошу помочь мне поменять версию для `apache` на более новою ! Не могу разобраться !*

**Как это сделать ?**

Comment: Какой апач используется? Который в комплекте с OS X шёл? Если да то он пользует php из /usr/bin точнее тот который обнаружился в по путям в переменной окружения PATH, а homebrew ставит софт по альтернативным путям как и macports эти пути они обычно добавляют в пользовательское окружение. Поэтому вы в cli видите одну версию, а в враче другую.

Answer (score 1):

[PHP разработчику под MacOS](http://anton.shevchuk.name/php/php-development-environment-under-macos/)

[Upgrading the Native PHP Installation on OS X Mountain Lion](https://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/upgrading-the-native-php-installation-on-os-x-mountain-lion--mac-4920)

Я пользовался этой сборкой - https://www.mamp.info/en/